# Null Pointer Exception error when calling method

Tags: exception, pointers, null

i have no idea what's wrong with what i am doing. It's supposed to print all patients who visited on a specific date but it keeps on throwing the null pointer error. It happens when I call on the printPatientsOnDate method.

code on the main/UI class

```
public void printPatientsOnDate() throws ParseException
{
    System.out.print("Enter the date(mm-dd-yyyy): ");
    Date dt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").parse(sc.nextLine());
    for(Patient i : app.getPatientsOnSpecDate(dt))
    {
    System.out.println(i.getName());
    }
}
```

code on the clinic class

```
public ArrayList<Patient> getPatientsOnSpecDate(Date date)
{
    ArrayList<Patient> patients = null;
    for(Patient i : patientList)
    {
      if(i.searchDates(date)!=null)
      {
        patients.add(i);
      }
    }
    return patients;
}
```

null pointer error code

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at pkg.Pagamutan.Clinic.UI.printPatientsOnDate(UI.java:81)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ArrayList<Patient> patients` reference variable is `null`. Currently it doesn't point to any `ArrayList<Patient>` object .

```
ArrayList<Patient> patients = null;
```

And when you trying to invoke `.add()` on that `null` reference it throws [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

> Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required.
>
> **These include:**
>
> Calling the instance method of a null object.
>   .............

You need to instantiate an `ArrayList<Patient>` object before invoking `.add()` on it.

```
ArrayList<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<Patient>();
```

Or better use `List<Patient>` as the reference type :

```
List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<Patient>();
```

Comment: thanks a lot! the error doesnt pop up but i have another problem. printPatientsOnDate does not print out any patients when called. is there something wrong with the for each loop?

Comment: Show us the running code , probably open a new question with that code . We cannot debug with just two random methods !